# build folder link to unexisted path

Tags: kernel, drivers, compiling

I installed CentOS 8.

```
CentOS-8-x86_64-1905-dvd1.iso
```

I need to compile a driver, I did:

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

After that, I still can't make driver source code ( by using 'make'), it reports build path is empty ( no such file or directory )

```
make[l]: *** /lib/modules/4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64/build: No such file or directory
```

l checked the build path in /lib/modules/4.18.0-80.el8.x86-64, it link to:

```
build -> /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64
```

but this path didn't exist.
What inside /usr/src/kernels is

```
4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64
```

If I do:

```
sudo yum install kernel-devel
```

it reports:

```
Package kernel-devel-4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64 is already installed.
```

**UPDATE**

If I manually change the KERNEL_SRC in Makefile

from

```
KERNEL_SRC :=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/
```

to

```
KERNEL_SRC :=/usr/src/kernel/4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64/
```

It can build, my problem is I install kernel-devel via yum, why it didn't create the correct kernel src path?

Comment: "_I still can't make driver source code, it reports build path is empty ( no such file or directory )_" Please add exact commands and exact error messages

Comment: updated, thanks.

Comment: "_I still can't make driver source code_" what's the exact command you used?

Comment: I just use 'make' then show the error as I posted.

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to build?

Comment: a NIC source driver, it is not public.

Comment: Have you tried repointing the dangling `build` symlink to the file you found that does exist?

Comment: that will work, but I don't know why yum didn't install the correct path.

Comment: Just ran in to the same problem.  This has got to be some sort of a packaging issue with the kernel source packages on centos 8, I can't believe it's still a problem with the latest package.

Comment: Update: seems to be a package version mismatch problem.  It seems there is no method to force the corresponding kernel and kernel header packages to be installed.  I was running an older kernel package, and the version mismatch was the problem.